# res.format negotiator with express router get post

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js

Saw the [express content negotiator](http://devdocs.io/express/index#res.format) and I wanna use to handle responses depending on content headers that came in.

For instance, this is my `.get()`.

```
authRoute.route('/login')
.get(function(req, res) {
  res.format({
    'text/html': function() {
      res.render('login', {
        user: req.user,
        error: req.flash('error'),
        loginMessage: req.flash('loginMessage'),
        active: 'login'
      });
    },
    'application/json': function() {
      res.json({
        message: 'This is login page'
      })
    }
  })
})
```

All what I'm trying to do is, if the request header is standard text/html, it should show the html page and a json response if request is application/json.

Problem is, it doesn't intercept the headers properly. Although I make the request (via Postman), setting the headers to be the `application/json`, it still displays the first condition in the `res.format({..})`

The above *always* displays `text/plain` instead of matching the right condition.

Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

```
authRoute.route('/login')

....

.post(passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
  successRedirect: '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
  failureRedirect: '/register', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
  failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you may be using the wrong header in the request (perhaps `Content-Type`?). You need to use the `Accept` header. Also, your text says `json/application`; that should be `application/json`, of course.

I don't use Postman, but using cURL it works just fine:

```
$ curl -H'Accept:application/json' http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: of course, it was a typo, the `json/application` in the question. Thanks. I was  sending Content-Type, thus why express couldn't pick it up. Tried with Accept, and working.

Answer (score 0):

Sample demo using `req.headers`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var contentType = req.headers['content-type'];
    if(contentType === 'application/json') {
        return res.json({
            message: 'This is login page'
        });
    }
    res.render('login', { // if not explicitly set, return default render
        user: req.user,
        error: req.flash('error'),
        loginMessage: req.flash('loginMessage'),
        active: 'login'
    });
});

app.listen(3001, function () {
    console.log('open localhost:3001');
});
```

Test in curl

```
curl localhost:3001 -H "content-type: application/json"
```

Comment: `Content-Type` is used to signify the content type of the request body, it's not meant to use for content negotiation.